# How can I get pyopengl working in my IDE?

Tags: python, opengl, pycharm, spyder, pyopengl

I'm fairly new to Python so it might be that I'm missing something but when I try to run a program that uses pyopengl it works in the standard Python IDLE but not in Spyder or Pycharm. At least, it works reliably in the standard IDLE and when I used it in Spyder it worked the first time, then I saved the program and when I loaded it again it came up with the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GL'; 'OpenGL' is not a package" error although the program worked fine before that and I didn't uninstall any packages in between.

Also when I try to import pyopengl it gives the same modulenotfounderror, but somehow it still runs my code that uses this module. (In the normal IDLE, Spyder ran the code twice, the second time after uninstalling and installing pyopengl a dozen times in many different ways, and Pycharm failed since the beginning).

I have tried reïnstalling the package via pip install pyopengl in the CMD and conda install pyopengl in the anaconda prompt. Every time it tells me that the packages are installed. No errors whatsoever.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

this part of the code fails every time, but when I try to import pyopengl through the console it also gives me the error I mentioned before

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please update Spyder to its latest version (3.3.4). That could solve the `ModuleNotFoundError` you're seeing.